# How can I squeeze the div and text within it and keep it responsive as well?

Tags: html, css, position, responsive, skew

I got as home[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRq1n.jpg): [https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRq1n.jpg][1]work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRq1n.jpg%5D%5B1%5Dwork), to make a website similar to the image attached.
I got stuck on getting the div with "TECHNOLOGY" to make it squeezed (top right) along with the text inside and also to make in it responsive and stay within the parent div.
One extra advice if I may, is about the text bellow the image that is on position absolute and gets bigger when on mobile.

Thanks!

```css
body, html{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 960px;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
}
/* ****Start Nav******** */
nav ul{
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content: center;
}

li a{
    display: flex;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2px;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(34, 101, 169);
}
/* ************* End Nav *************** */
/* ******Start 2nd Row with Title********** */
.name{
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px 40px;
    align-items: center;

}
.title {
    Flex: 0 1 auto;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.title2{
    padding-left: 10px;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.contact{
    margin-left: 0 auto;
    line-height: 3px;
    font-size: 0.7rem;
}
/* ******End 2nd Row with Title********** */
/* ********Start blue box with containers */
.blue {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    display: flex;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0px 40px;
    height: 53vh;
    background-color: rgb(189, 217, 254);
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.tech{
    padding: 0px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(49, 137, 77);
    text-align: justify;
    transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(20deg) scaleX(6) scaleY(10);
}
.box1, .box2{
    background-color: rgb(34, 101, 169);
    color: white;
}
.box1{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 316px;
    top: 2em;
    left: 2em;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 10px;
}
.box1::first-line{
    width: 220px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed white;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}
.box2{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    top: 31rem;
    right: 22rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3.8rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <title>Implementing a Layout using HTML & CSS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">about us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="">company</a></li>
        <li><a href="">services</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="name">
        <div class="title">TechCorporate</div>
        <div class="title2">Free PSD Website Template</div>
        <div class="contact">
            <p>Tel: xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx</p>
            <p>Mail: info@domain.com</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
        <div class="tech">TECHNOLOGY</div>
        <div class="box1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet das</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat, unde debitis quibusdam quas accusantium ipsa officia quo iste delectus modi voluptatibus harum rem saepe quod maxime quam. Velit, beatae quos ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur  elit. Placeat, unde debitis.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">Todays Technology »</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of work to do, I started to fix it.
You need to use media queries.

```css
body, html{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 960px;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
}
/* ****Start Nav******** */
nav ul{
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content: center;
}

li a{
    display: flex;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2px;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(34, 101, 169);
}
/* ************* End Nav *************** */
/* ******Start 2nd Row with Title********** */
.name{
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px 40px;
    align-items: center;

}
.title {
    Flex: 0 1 auto;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.title2{
    padding-left: 10px;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.contact{
    margin-left: 0 auto;
    line-height: 3px;
    font-size: 0.7rem;
}
/* ******End 2nd Row with Title********** */
/* ********Start blue box with containers */
.blue {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    display: flex;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0px 40px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(189, 217, 254);
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.tech{
    padding: 0px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(49, 137, 77);
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 9vw;
    transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(20deg);
}

.box1, .box2{
    background-color: rgb(34, 101, 169);
    color: white;
}
.box1{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    max-width: 316px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    top: 2em;
    right: 2em;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 10px;
}
.box1::first-line{
    width: 220px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed white;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}
.box2{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    max-width: 20rem;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    left:20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
.blue {
height: 53vh;
}
.tech{
font-size: 7rem;
}
.box2{
  font-size: 3.8rem;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <title>Implementing a Layout using HTML & CSS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">about us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="">company</a></li>
        <li><a href="">services</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="name">
        <div class="title">TechCorporate</div>
        <div class="title2">Free PSD Website Template</div>
        <div class="contact">
            <p>Tel: xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx</p>
            <p>Mail: info@domain.com</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
        <div class="tech">TECHNOLOGY</div>
        <div class="box1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet das</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat, unde debitis quibusdam quas accusantium ipsa officia quo iste delectus modi voluptatibus harum rem saepe quod maxime quam. Velit, beatae quos ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur  elit. Placeat, unde debitis.</p>
        </div>
         <div class="box2">Todays Technology »</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can imagine :( especially on the responsive part, but to be honest, I'm more fixated about the tech div to make it like in the picture and then make it responsive.